# What's ARM instruction equivalent to Intel's xchgl?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, arm

I found `LDREX` and `STREX` might be the ones to use. But they are *two* instructions (and thus not provide the atomicity of `xchgl`). The value I want to exchange atomically is a 32-bit value.
Can `LDREX` and `STREX` be used in a way that provides atomic exchange of a 32-bit value or are they other ways to achieve it (provided it works on armv7l or higher)?

Normally, I'd the gcc's [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) or the more recent (C++11 equivalent) [builtin functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) 
for such atomic operations. But in this case, I have to use inline assembly in C (to port an x86-based futex implementation to ARM architecture). Thanks!

Comment: Not every x86 instruction has an ARM equivalent..

Comment: A good starting point in these cases is to look at the code generated by the compiler - try using the gcc builtin atomics and see what assembly gets generated.

Comment: You probably could use [C11 `<stdatomic.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) in your futex implementation, even though Linux kernel / low-level stuff generally favours GNU C inline-asm.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_exchange.  But if you want to use inline-asm, first look at how a compiler compiles a stdatomic version of what you want (as Fuz points out).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for suggestion. It's indeed a good idea to C11 atomics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the ARM instruction set, there is no atomic exchange instruction. Instead you use `ldrex` and `strex` and code like this:

```
@ exchange r0 and [r1]
ldrex r2,[r1]
strex r3, r0,[r1]
mov   r0,r2
```

When `[r1]` is modified between `ldrex` and `strex` or the exchange cannot be guaranteed to be atomic for some other reason, 1 is returned in `r3` and the store isn't performed. If the sequence is atomic, 0 is returned. Thus, by executing this snippet in a loop until you get a zero `r3` you can eventually reach an atomic exchange operation. That's actually how gcc and clang implement the corresponding intrinsic; pass `-S` to the compiler to observe what it does.

Comment: Good idea to use `-S`. I have used it a number of times before yet I needed it, it completely missed me :)

Answer (score 2):

SWP is still supported on some cores despite what the docs say (they often say please dont use rather than we have removed it) but it is going away or may be gone on your core.

Atomics are costly, CISC is costly so perhaps it is fine there, but RISC it makes sense what they have done.  You are basically synthesizing the atomic but you may have to repeat it until it works (rather than stopping all data movement on the bus while the atomic happens).  Not limited to a RISC/CISC thing but simply a performance thing.

Comment: Interestingly, ARM has reintroduced atomics on AArch64.