# Lock-free atomic operations on ARM architectures prior to ARMv6

Tags: c, arm, atomic, lock-free

Are there any implementations thereof in C? All those I've seen so far are based on the LDREX/STREX instructions, which were introduced only in the ARMv6 architecture. The only possible solution for previous architectures seems to be to disable/enable IRQs, which makes the operations blocking.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43640556/4389800. If you can use C11, look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic to do "in C". Even otherwise, you can write it in C11 and look at the assembly to use on your older-than-armv6 architecture (if you can't make use of C11 directly).

Comment: There used to be a `SWP` and `SWPB` instruction that atomically swaps contents between a register and memory. It's removed by ARMv7 IIRC.

Comment: According to [this document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/DHT0008A_arm_synchronization_primitives.pdf), `LDREX` in some form was added in ARMv6.

Answer (score -1):

> Are there any implementations thereof in C?

No.  It is impossible to implement this is 'C' without support from the compiler or assembly (assembly support in compiler).  'C' has no instruction to guarantee that something executes atomically.

> The only possible solution for previous architectures seems to be to disable/enable IRQs, which makes the operations blocking.

Many lock-free algorithms need 'CAS' (compare-and-set).  `swp` and `swpb` can be used to do some primitive four value operations, but they are not CAS.  In order to do four sources and one consumer, you can give each of four bytes to the sources, using `swpb` and have the consumer use `swp` to transfer the four 'work' bytes.  Most ARM cpus prior to ARMv6 are single core and locking interrupts is the common way to do things.  ARMv6 cores have support for LDREX/STREX.  The `swp` instruction is not multi-cpu friendly as it locks the entire bus for the transaction (read/write).  However, `swp` can be used for spin locks if it is the only thing available.

Linux has support for a 'compare and exchange' with [OS help](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S?h=v4.12#n941).  The gist is that a small fixed assembler sequence does the compare and exchange.  Interrupt and data abort code is hooked to make sure if this code is interrupted that it is restarted.

Comment: @Lundin The OP may have a bare metal OS.  _Atomic is for read/write only.  The is no way to atomically 'compare and set' with atomic.  Algorithms like a ring buffer with single reader/writer will work with `_Atomic`, but more sophisticated **lock free** algorithms won't.  I see the OP tagged his question with both **lock free** and **atomic**.  They are quite different concepts; The OP seems to search for a `ldrex` and `strex` replacement as he is probably trying to port newer code to an older CPU.  `swp` and locking interrupts are the only generic way without more specifics on his issue.

Comment: Also important; some ARM CPUs feature restartable `ldm` and `stm` instructions.  `ldm` and `stm` can possibly be used as `multi-word` atomics on CPUs without restarting (as well as `ldrd` and `strd` featured on some ARMv5 CPUs).  Note that **NOT** restarting these instructions will increase interrupt (and FIQ) latency.  My answer was focused on the tag 'lock-free' and the `ldrex` in the question.  For atomic reads/writes any bus size load/store is fine without caches.  `_Atomic` may not work correctly with a bare metal cache enabled system (and DMA etc).  Ie, even atomic might need OS support.